How to prove the following recursion converges to 1/e?
I was trying to solve another problem when I came across the following recursion.

For $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, define
$f(0,k)=1$ if $k=0$ else $0$,
$f(n,k)=\frac{1}{k+2}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} f(n-1,i).$

Interestingly, I found that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n,0)=\frac1e.$$
This result can be verified with the following python code.
N=20
x=[1/(i+2) for i in range(N)]
for _ in range(N-1):
    x=[sum(x[:i+2])/(i+2) for i in range(N)]
    print(x[0])

Output:
0.41666666666666663
0.38888888888888884
0.3775462962962962
0.37248070987654314
0.3701115428424455
0.368974461079442
0.3684203334597574
0.3681477697205656
0.36801291996966423
0.36794595687761744
0.3679126256059
0.3678960091921909
0.3678877171835366
0.36788357652784043
0.3678815079704671
0.36788047427889375
0.367879957628061
0.3678796993674438
0.3678795702586889

However, I failed to prove this result. Below are my attempts.

Using fixed point

Let $x_k=f(\infty,k)=\frac{1}{k+2}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} x_i$, we have $x_1=x_2=x_3=$...
Not very helpful.

Using generating function

Let $G_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(n,k)x^k$, we have
$G_0(x)=1,$
$G_1(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+2}x^k=\frac{1}{x^2}(\ln\frac{1}{1-x}-(1+x)),$
$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2G_{n+1}(x))=\frac1{1-x}G_n(x)-G_n(0).$
It seems that there is not a clear pattern for $G_n(x)$ and the recursion is not easy to solve.

So how can we prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n,0)=\frac1e$?

Please show your attempts.

@TheSilverDoe I was trying to solve another problem and transformed it into this recursion. I verified with python that it converges to $1/e$ but failed to prove this limit.

@JohnAo you should include all that in the question body or no one is gonna take your ques seriously and it will be closed soon enough and that too unanswered

I found a proof. I'll post it if it's re-opened. Hint: think backwards.

@YiJiang Could you elaborate on this "backwards" idea? I tried to list $f(n,k)$ in layers by $n$ and "distribute" the value from bottom layer to top, but still cannot find a clear pattern.

@yijiang the question is reopened

@JohnAo Oh, never mind that, I found an equivalent but more intuitive way to solve it. See the answer below.

Consider this initial sequence, $f(0,k)=\delta_{0k}, k=0,\dots,\infty$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.
Next, we define $f(n,k)=\frac{1}{k+2}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}f(n-1,i)$, which is the average of the first $k+2$ numbers in the previous sequence. Thus, the first few sequences are,
$$1,0,0,0,\dots$$
$$\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots$$
$$\frac{5}{12},\frac{13}{36},\frac{77}{240},\dots$$
The question is, what is $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n,0)$? Does it converge to $e^{-1}$?
Other forms:
If we write the sequence as a vector $v_n$, the vector of the next sequence is the previous one multiplied by a matrix $M$, $v_{n+1}=Mv_n$, where
$$M=
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
    \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
    \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
    \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & \dots\\
     &  &  & \dots & & & \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
We start from the vector $v_0=(1,0,0,\dots)$, thus the first element of $v_{n}$ is just the top left element of $M^n$. Thus the question becomes if $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} [M^n]_{00}=e^{-1}$.
Another way to see it is thinking backwards. Consider the first element of the $n$th sequence. It equals $\frac{1}{2}$ of the sum of the first two elements of the $(n-1)$th sequence. We can continue to write it as the weighted sum of the previous sequence, and so on. Let's write the weight on each element for each sequence, starting from the $n$th sequence.
$$
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{matrix}
    1 & & & &\\
    \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & & &\\
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2} &  &\\
    \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2} & \dots & & &
\end{matrix}$$
We can express the denominators as products of paths. Consider the sequences of length $n$, $\{P_n\}$, which start with $p_0=2$, and each time the next number $p_k$ can be any number within $[2,1+p_{k-1}]$ for $k\in [1,n-1]$. The first few sets are:
\begin{align*}n=1:& (2)\\
n=2:& (2,2),(2,3)\\
n=3:& (2,2,2),(2,2,3),(2,3,2),(2,3,3),(2,3,4)\\
n=4:& (2,2,2,2),(2,2,2,3),(2,2,3,2),(2,2,3,3),(2,2,3,4),(2,3,2,2),(2,3,2,3),(2,3,3,2),\\
 &(2,3,3,3),(2,3,3,4),(2,3,4,2),(2,3,4,3),(2,3,4,4),(2,3,4,5)
\end{align*}
Let $P_{nj}$ be any path in $\{P_n\}$, and $\prod P_{nj}$ be the product of all the numbers in that path. The question is equivalent to $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{P_{nj}\in \{P_n\}} (\prod P_{nj})^{-1}=e^{-1}$.
Notice that these sequences of weights are exactly the first row of $M^n$, thus they are totally equivalent. Relating them to the "product of paths" seems like an interesting connection.
Proof:
Consider the eigenvectors of the matrix, $M$. An obvious one is an all one vector, $u=(1,1,1,\dots)$. Apparently $Mu=u$, thus, $M^n u=u$, which implies that every row of $M^n$ must sum to 1. Can we use this to find $[M^n]_{00}$?
Suppose the first row of $M^{n-1}$ is $(a_{n-1,0},\ a_{n-1,1},\ a_{n-1,2},\ \dots)$. Multiply $M^{n-1}$ to $M$, the elements of the first row of $M^n$ are:
\begin{align*}
a_{n0}=&\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1,0}+\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1,1}+\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1,2}+\dots\\
a_{n1}=&\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1,0}+\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1,1}+\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1,2}+\dots\\
a_{n2}=&\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1,1}+\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1,2}+\dots\\
a_{n3}=&\frac{1}{4}a_{n-1,2}+\dots
\end{align*}
Evidently,
\begin{align*}
a_{n1}&=a_{n0},\\
a_{n2}&=a_{n1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1,0},\\
a_{n3}&=a_{n2}-\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1,1},\\
\dots
\end{align*}
Assuming that the first row of $M^n$ converges (which will be proved shortly after) to a constant vector $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)$. Then we must have
\begin{align*}
a_1&=a_0\\
a_2&=a_1-\frac{1}{2}a_0\\
a_3&=a_2-\frac{1}{3}a_1\\
a_4&=a_3-\frac{1}{4}a_2\\
\dots
\end{align*}
It's easy to solve for the first few elements as a function of $a_0$, namely
$a_1=a_0, a_2=\frac{1}{2}a_0, a_3=\frac{1}{6}a_0, a_4=\frac{1}{24}a_0$. The pattern is obvious.
It's easy to prove the general formula $a_k=\frac{1}{k!}a_0$ by induction, since $\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}=\frac{1}{k!}-\frac{k}{k+1}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$.
Since we must have $\sum a_i=1$, we have $(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{i!})a_0=1$, thus $a_0=e^{-1}$.
To prove that the first row of $M^n$ converges, first we prove that $a_{n0}$ must converge. Consider the original form of the problem. We start with a decreasing sequence, $(1,0,0,0,\dots)$. Each time, the $k$th element of the next sequence is the average of the first $k+2$ elements of the current sequence. If the current sequence is decreasing, it's easy to show that the next sequence must also be decreasing. Thus, $f(n,0)=\frac{1}{2}(f(n-1,0)+f(n-1,1))<f(n-1,0)$ for any $n$. We proved that $f(n,0)$ decreases with $n$. Since $f(n,0)>0$, the limit must exist, thus $a_{n0}$ must converge.
From the updating rule,
\begin{align*}
a_{n1}&=a_{n0},\\
a_{n2}&=a_{n1}-\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1,0},\\
a_{n3}&=a_{n2}-\frac{1}{3}a_{n-1,1},\\
\dots
\end{align*}
If $a_{n0}$ converges, $a_{n1}=a_{n0}$ must also converge, then $a_{n2}$ must converge as well. The same goes for the rest of the elements, thus the sequence must converge. The proof is complete.

I see what I've been missing. I tried $M^n=MM^{n-1}$ and only got the conclusion that the elements of the first column of $M^n$ must all be equal but could not figure out its value. While using $M^n=M^{n-1}M$ leads to $a_{k+1}=a_k-\frac{1}{k+1}a_{k-1}$ and solves the problem.
